# Complex order by

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by, case

I have an order by in a mssql query that needs to be ordered in a complex way. I could solve this using a cursor but it is not a optimal solution.

My select returns a table with user entry and exit, time of entry, and time of exit and I need to sort the earliest entry followed by his exit, then second earliest entry followed by that persons exists, etc. so for example

date----  user ----   action (1 being entry 2 being exit)

0622 ---- 4 ---------       1

0627  ----   4 ---------      2

0623  ----   1  ---------     1

0624  ----   1  ---------     2

0624  ----   3  ---------     1

0630  ----   3  ---------     2

0701 ---- 4 ---------       1

0703  ----   4 ---------      2

I thought about using case where on the order by but I do not know how to have this result.

Thank you for the help,

Comment: What is your current query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
select
    your_table.[date],
    your_table.[user],
    your_table.[action]
from your_table
order by
    (case when your_table.[action]=1 then your_table.[date] else (select max(t.[date]) from your_table t where t.[action]=1 and t.[user]=your_table.[user] and t.[date]<=your_table.[date]) end),
    your_table.[user],
    your_table.[action];
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier, I have to check your solution, which I will do soon